# NPM package description is bugged

Tags: javascript, npm, markdown, readme

I made a npm package today but the readme file shows not up correctly on the npm page:
https://npmjs.com/package/botmakerdiscord
this is my readme: 
https://github.com/lugosieben/discordbotmaker/blob/main/README.md

and thats how it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpMgT.png

Comment: Currently the _README.md_  file in [your tarball](https://registry.npmjs.org/botmakerdiscord/-/botmakerdiscord-0.4.3.tgz) which has been published to the npm registry is encoded as `text/x-c++; charset=utf-16le` - You need to change the files encoding to `text/plain; charset=us-ascii`, then republish your package to the npm registry.

Comment: Thank you but how do i do that?

Comment: On _*nix_ you can utilize the [iconv](https://ss64.com/bash/iconv.html) command line tool. E.g. Run the following command: `iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 ./some/path/to/README.md > ./some/path/to/new-README.md`

Comment: That's something you don't normally do in per-file basis. Instead, you configure your IDE or editor to save files in UTF-8 (which is normally the default, since ASCII or UTF-16 are not as common or useful nowadays).